# unpickling HasTraits object: how to prevent assignment of certain traits

Tags: python, pickle, traits, enthought

I have a HasTraits object which is written and read from disk using cPickle. The object has a certain trait that is computationally expensive to *assign*. From the [traits documentation](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/traits_user_manual/advanced.html#unpickling-hastraits-objects) , I understand that all of the  traits are being *re-asigned* when an object is read from disk.

I would like to prevent the expensive trait from being re-assigned when the object is read from disk. Is this possible?

Comment: just a hint, you should use cPickle, it can be up to 1000 times faster in reading and writing

Comment: im not sure whether this is relavent or will work, but maybe pickle the object youre assigning the traits to?

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal , i am using cPickle, i have edited the post to reflect this. i dont understand your second comment.

Comment: you said that assigning the trait is costly, cant you pickle the assigned object? I don't know if its relevant or if i understand your problem.

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal , perhaps my question is unclear. I am pickling a HasTraits object. the problem is that when i un-pickle it, all traits are automatically assigned, and this is computationally expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Make this trait transient as described here:
http://docs.enthought.com/traits/traits_user_manual/advanced.html#persistence
(BTW, note that this is a somewhat newer version of the docs than you linked to, though this section is in both versions.)

Comment: The problem is that i want to trait to have the correct value, but i dont want to have the entire `depends_on` chain response occur.perhaps this is impossible, i dont have detailed knowledge of Pickle. the reason i dont want/need the expensive trait to be re-assigned, is that if it had the value when pickled, then all traits that `depend_on` the expensive trait have already reacted accordingly.

Comment: i think this requires another trait attribute slightly different than `transient`. maybe a  trait which is `psuedo-transient` will skip the `Notification` step (http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/) when unpickled.